# Download Azure Blob with Shared Access Signature using wget or curl

Tags: curl, wget, azure-blob-storage

*I know I can use the Azure CLI to accomplish this, but I'd like to use common Linux/Unix commands.*

I have an Azure Blob Container, which is private. Let's call it https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/my-blob-container/my-file.my-extension.

If my container is set to "Public read access for blobs only", everything works great.

```
$ wget https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/my-blob-container/my-file.my-extension
--2016-04-28 16:11:15-- https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/my-blob-container/my-file.my-extension
Resolving my-account.blob.core.windows.net (my-account.blob.core.windows.net)... 4.11.2.14
Connecting to my-account.blob.core.windows.net (my-account.blob.core.windows.net)|4.11.2.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 21682 (21K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘my-file.my-extension’
```

If my container is set to "No public access", and I create an Access policy called `my-policy`, with Read/Write/Delete/List for one year, I get the following direct link: `https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/my-blob-container/my-file.my-extension?sv=2015-02-21&si=my-policy&sr=b&sig=y%2B2pvIuR9rGQdvm%2FQKp0xNCWE%2B1G%2F2IqjHkWMhRcPUA%3D`

If I copy the link into a browser, the file downloads automatically. If I use `wget`, I get a 404 error:

```
$ wget https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/my-blob-container/my-file.my-extension?sv=2015-02-21&si=my-policy&sr=b&sig=y%2B2pvIuR9rGQdvm%2FQKp0xNCWE%2B1G%2F2IqjHkWMhRcPUA%3D
[4] 14106
[5] 14107
[6] 14108
[2]   Done                    si=my-policy
[3]   Done                    sr=b
$ --2016-04-29 01:25:54--  https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/my-blob-container/my-file.my-extension?sv=2015-02-21
Resolving my-account.blob.core.windows.net (my-account.blob.core.windows.net)... 4.11.2.14
Connecting to my-account.blob.core.windows.net (my-account.blob.core.windows.net)|4.11.2.14|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 The specified resource does not exist.
2016-04-29 01:25:54 ERROR 404: The specified resource does not exist..
```

`wget` returns Exit Stats 8 ("Server issued an error response").

Comment: Hi, did my answer help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @step-locke. I have tried adding `st`, `se`, and `sp` as you suggest, but the error message is the same (`HTTP/1.1 404 The specified resource does not exist.`). It still puzzles me because a web browser has no difficulty downloading the file with exactly the same URL.

Comment: I've added an update. It looks like the key diff between our cmd-lines causes the error - you're not quoting the url. When I don't quote the URL, it too generates a 404 error

Comment: You are correct; everything works as long as the URL is quoted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: sometimes you just need to put the address in quotes ("https:// ....")

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The query is difficult to debug without the specifics but...

**You must make sure that the URL is enclosed in speech marks when making the wget call due to the nature of some of the URL encoding** (it's the same if you're doing a `curl`)

I can create a SAS at the container level that allows me to read a file in storage

```
wget "https://azurerpkg.blob.core.windows.net/azurer/doggies.jpg?st=2016-06-06T07%3A56%3A00Z&se=2018-06-07T07%3A56%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-04-05&sr=c&sig=nKQz5BcWoUaASBzSW7Hv0TzfMbTFcf0f%2B5mMtmTwQ2A%3D" -k -O "doggies.jpg"
```

If I create a specific SAS at the blob level my wget also works

```
wget "https://azurerpkg.blob.core.windows.net/azurer/doggies.jpg?st=2016-06-06T07%3A56%3A00Z&se=2018-06-07T07%3A56%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=ntNFXS6fUlHVkiqoqj2rHg1Pw6gSNosnYqj3CQ6GIrg%3D" -k -O doggies.jpg
```

A valid shared access signature query string requires arguments for the following parameters:

- st
- se
- sp
- sr
- sig

Yours appears to be missing the `se` component which is the expiry date.

Comment: To be clear: the reason this works is because the URL is quoted. I don't know if it has something to do with the question mark/ampersands needing quotes, but I suspect it has nothing to do with Azure.