# Download Azure Blob using HTTP Basic Auth using Azure AD Credentials

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Storage Account with public access disabled. Inside the storage account are a few Blob Storage Containers. Each container has access managed with AzureAD with varying permissions for each user/group to different Blob Containers.

I want to be able to download items inside the Blob Storage using tools like `wget` or `curl` using HTTP Basic Auth or specifying user information in the request.

I'm aware that AzCopy can be used to download Blobs from the containers, but previously we have used http requests to download artifacts and would like to continue using that method.

[This question from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927341/download-azure-blob-with-shared-access-signature-using-wget-or-curl) Makes it seem like that its possible to do this with Shared Access Signature, which makes me believe that its possible to use with User Delegation SAS, but I have not found a way to set this up, and it requires a lot of parameters, more than a username/password or token.

Does Azure Blob Storage have a way where a user can access blob storage without AzCopy or any other specialized tools and authenticate via a method that does not require additional resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You must make a separate request for a token to send to Blob.

> When a security principal (a user, group, or application) attempts to
> access a blob resource, the request must be authorized, unless it is a
> blob available for anonymous access. With Azure AD, access to a
> resource is a two-step process. First, the security principal's
> identity is authenticated and an OAuth 2.0 token is returned. Next,
> the token is passed as part of a request to the Blob service and used
> by the service to authorize access to the specified resource.
>
> The authentication step requires that an application request an OAuth
> 2.0 access token at runtime.

[Overview of Azure AD for blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#overview-of-azure-ad-for-blobs)